# assign middleware to controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, middleware

I have laravel 5.6 project 
and I have registered middleware called `permissions`. I need to assign this middleware in a controller, but not for the whole `controller`- just for one `function` without using `__construct()`.

I mean I want to assign this in:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->middleware('permission');
}
```

I've tried it like this, but its not working. It's worked when I use it inside:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('permission');
}
```

But I don't need it like that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('permission')->only('index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Middleware can only be registered in the constructor. You can use the `only()` method though, like:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('permission')->only('index');
}
```

I believe you can pass an array of middlewares as well. There's also the `except()` method that does the opposite.